# Using a Typescript anonymous class in a type qualifier

Tags: typescript, generics, types, anonymous-class

I'm attempting to create a generic table builder class. Within the table builder, I define an anonymous class which stores column definitions. I would like the table builder to store instances of these definitions in an array. Here is the simplified class definition I'm currently working with:

```js
export class TableBuilder<T> {

  Column = class {
    constructor(public data: T) {}
  }

  private columns: Array<TableBuilder['Column']>

  column(data: T) {
    const col = new this.Column(data);
    this.columns.push(col);
  }
}
```

The line `this.columns.push(col)` throws a compile-time error: **Argument of type '(anonymous class)' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof (anonymous class)'**

Is there a way to define the `columns` member as an array of anonymous class instances? I can define it as type `any[]`, but I would prefer a solution that preserves type enforcement of column entries.

Comment: Your code gives different errors in the [typescript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=7&ssc=26&pln=7&pc=40#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4BUUCMnABCArgJZIAmwUAPFgHxwDeAUC3HAMIRLEC2AOzgBeRKgzN2HRBAFoYUYghjQAFGGL5SCOBRQwUALmwBKZgF8plqWCikAbvuAzegtMYCCUKCgCedPAISciooAG0Acm5XAQiAXXo2DgQefgFVPQNjLDNWaRk5eBSkETgBYAB3OBgAC1I0ADpotIz9FBMAbikOWvqG4rTGjTQa1WLOqxZzIA) Can you provide a complete example that shows the errors your getting there?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a custom constructor type which produces column objects with a specific interface. Something like that:

```js
interface IColumn<T> {
    //define column interface here
}

interface IColumnConstructor<T> {
    new(data: T): IColumn<T>;
}

class TableBuilder<T> {
    private Column: IColumnConstructor<T> = class<T> {
        constructor(public data: T) { }
    }

    private columns: IColumn<T>[] = [];

    public column(data: T) {
        const instance = new this.Column(data);
        this.columns.push(instance);
    }
}
```

Your anonymous `class<T>` class must be compatible with the `ColumnInterface<T>` interface if this scenario.